# How to parse enums by value from query parameters using webargs?

Tags: python, flask, python-3.7, flask-marshmallow, webargs

I have the next enum:

```
class EStatus(enum.IntEnum):
    NEW = 0
    MODIFIED = 1
```

And schema:

```
ARGS = {
    'status': EnumField(EStatus, by_value=True, required=False)
}
```

After in Flask I declared GET-method with `webargs`:

```
@use_args(ARGS, location='query')
def get(self, args: Dict[str, any]):
    return []
```

And it fails with error:

```
{'messages': {'query': {'status': ['Invalid enum value 1']}}, 'schema': <GeneratedSchema(many=False)>, 'headers': None}
```

I've checked it in debugger and found that `EnumField` calls `EStatus(value)`. The problem is that my value is `str` type because of it's from query parameters.

How to make to `EnumField` cast it to `int` before call `EStatus(value)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class EStatus(enum.IntEnum):
    NEW = 0
    MODIFIED = 1

  @staticmethod
    def from_str(e_status: str):
        e_status = e_status.upper()
        if e_status in EStatus.__members__:
            return EStatus[e_status]
        else:
            raise ValueError(f'{e_status} is not a valid EStatus.')

#You can use above from_str like below,
EStatus e_status = EStatus.from_str('NEW')
print(e_status.name)
print(e_status.value)
```

Hopefully for your problem you should be able to convert str to Enum type using from_str staticmethod.